# JavaScript игнорирует код после цикла

Tags: javascript

Пришлось столкнуться с js, который я в целом знаю лишь на самом начальном уровне. Есть небольшая функция:

```
$('.buttcart_tocart').click(function()
{
    var items = $('tr[data-id]');
    var result = true;
    for(var item in items)
    {
      //some code
      result = false;
    }
    console.log(result);
    return result;
});
```

Проблема в том, что после выполнения цикла остальной код игнорируется. Причина для меня не ясна. Ошибок в консоль не выводится. Функция работает, как и ожидается, за исключением строк после окончания цикла.

Comment: Вообще-то все работает вполне ожидаемо и предсказуемо.

Comment: Можно объяснить?

Comment: Что объяснить?

Comment: Коммент из серии "это вам не нужно".

Почему бы не использовать

    items.each(function(){
      //some code
    });

?

Comment: Почему ожидаемо то, что код после цикла не выполняется?

Comment: @DanielOlivo, http://jsfiddle.net/924o61m4/ - потому что все работает, увы. :)

НО!!!
Все-таки конструкция 

    for(var item in items)

Требует исключительной аккуратности обращения. Особенно, когда вы точно не знаете, что такое items ;)

Comment: Вы меня неверно поняли. Я не говорил, что это ожидаемо. Я говорил, что ваш код работает без неожиданностей - код после цикла выполняется. Во всяком случае если вместо неизвестно что содержащего $('tr[data-id]') подставить какую-либо корректную последовательность, например, [1, 2, 3], то все вполне работает.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Похоже все дело было в коллекции, особенности jquery, полагаю. each() помогло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак. Поиграем в телепата.
Для начала, чтобы понять "почему", надо понять, что у вас под загадочным *"some code"*.
Лучше всего, показать этот кусочек.
Скорее всего, *"some code"* ожидает увидеть джикверевый элемент - строку таблицы. А фиг там: так как `for(var in arr)` возвращает **ВСЕ** свойства, то там, кроме строк, приходят еще и функции, левые свойства, прототипы... Короче, все то, что на джикверевые методы общения с домом реагировать НЕ будет. Соответственно, ошибка исполнения, error (который можно посмотреть все в той же консоли, как правило), смерть скрипта и остановка исполнения.

Даже `.hasOwnProperty()` нас тут не спасет (и в первом, и во втором случае вы можете в этом сами легко убедиться, вызвав `console.log(items[item]))`;

Что же делать?
Один из вариантов ответа:

http://jsfiddle.net/bmqgszsp/

```
$('.buttcart_tocart').click(function()
{
    "use strict";
    var items = $('tr[data-id]');
    var result = true;
    items.each(function(){
        "use strict";
        //some code
        result = false;
    });
    alert(result);
    return result;
});
```